# How can I filter this list by first and last name?

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I need the search bars to filter out the results by first and last name as shown in this link, https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/f-1/735fae21-9b8d-4431-8978-5098a2217fd2/part3.webm

I am very stumped on this problem. any assistance would be welcome.

thank you!

```
const apiInfo = $('.info');
const avg = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0) / arr.length;

const renderStudentInfo = (student, $target) => {
  const fullName = student.firstName + ' ' + student.lastName,
    average = avg(student.grades.map(grade => parseInt(grade, 10)));
  $target.append($(`
    <div class="infoB">
      <img class="pPic float-left m-3"
        src="${student.pic}" alt="profile pic" />
      <h4 class="title">${fullName}<h4>
      <p class="mb-1 stats">Email: ${student.email}</p>
      <p class="mb-1 stats">Comapny: ${student.company}</p>
      <p class="mb-1 stats">Skill: ${student.skill}</p>
      <p class="mb-1 stats">Average: ${average.toFixed(2)}%</p>
      <a href=# id="plus"><i class="mb-5 fa fa-plus float-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  `));
};

const init = () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students',
    method: 'GET',
  }).then(({ students }) => {
    students.forEach((student) => {
      if (student.id.includes('')) {
        renderStudentInfo(student, apiInfo);
      }
    });
  });
}

init();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="input mt-5 mx-5">
      <input
        id="nameSearch"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Search by name"
        aria-label="Search by name"
        aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="input mb-0 mt-2 mx-5">
      <input
        id="tagSearch"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Search tags"
        aria-label="Search tags"
        aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="container mt-0">
      <div class="info card scroll shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded"></div>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(243, 240, 240);
}

img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid rgb(156, 148, 148) 1px;
    min-width: 130px;
}

.infoB{
    border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
}

.stats{
    color: grey;
    margin-left: 175px;
}

.title{
    font-size: 50px;
}

.card {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.scroll {
    max-height: 575px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.fa-plus{
    color: grey;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You'll need to store all users
2. Handle input 'input' event
3. Clear apiInfo DOM node
4. Populate it with filtered students

Here is the code you need for 1, 2, 3, 4

```
...
const avg = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0) / arr.length; // Your code

// #2
const nameSeachInput = $('#nameSearch');
nameSeachInput.on('input',
  function() {
    apiInfo.empty();    // #3
    // #4
    allStudents.filter(student => student.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(this.value.toLowerCase()) || student.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(this.value.toLowerCase())).forEach(student => {
      if (student.id.includes('')) {
        renderStudentInfo(student, apiInfo);
      }
    });
  });
let allStudents;    // #1
```

And a bit more for #1

```
...
method: 'GET',
  }).then(({
    students
  }) => {
    allStudents = students;    // 1
    students.forEach((student) => {
      if (student.id.includes('')) {
        renderStudentInfo(student, apiInfo);
...
```